# Process output of a sequence of files in Matlab

Tags: file, matlab, sequence

**EDIT 3**

Hi! I had problems with the matrix dimensions but I've solved it. Now my problem is that I want to do the same operation on a large series of files on the same folder and I want write the output values on a separate line on text.txt. With the first one it works but it doesn't 'write' to the 'text', the rest. Is there something wrong?

```
myPath = 'C:\EX\'; 
a= dir (fullfile(myPath,'*.DIM')); 
fileNames = { a.name };

% Rename files
for k = 1:length(fileNames)
     newFileName = [fileNames{k}(1:2) fileNames{k}(4:6) '.txt']; 
     movefile([myPath fileNames{k}], [myPath newFileName]);
end

 filePattern=fullfile( myPath,'*.txt');
 txtFiles= dir(filePattern);    
   for k = 1:length(txtFiles)
    baseFileName=txtFiles(k).name;
    fullFileName= fullfile(myPath,baseFileName);
    fid=fopen(fullFileName, 'r');
    for i = 1:18
        m{i} = fgetl(fid);
    end
    result2 = m{18};
    result2b= result2([12:19]);

    fid=fopen(fullFileName, 'r');
    for i = 1:30
    m{i} = fgetl(fid);
    end
    result3 = m{30};
    result3b= result3([12:19]);

    fid=fopen(fullFileName, 'r');
    for i = 1:31
    m{i} = fgetl(fid);
    end
    result4 = m{31};
    result4b= result4([12:20]);

    fid=fopen(fullFileName, 'r');
    for i = 1:19
    m{i} = fgetl(fid);
    end
    result5 = m{19};
    result5b= result5([12:20]);

  text= {baseFileName, result2b, result3b, result4b, result5b};
    final= [Fields'; text];

       end
```

Really thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to apply the same operation/function on a large series of files? and then write the output of each on a separate line in `test.txt` ?

Comment: Thanks Gunther for you reply. Yes, that's exactly what I want to do but it doesn't work. :( I've just edited the question again.

Answer (score 0):

Index exceeds dimensions is exactly what it means.

Try to put a breakpoint at the line where it occurs and check the dimension of result2. Assuming it is a vector, you will find that its length is less than 19.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Dennis. I've checked it but I don't know how to solve the problem. If I evaluate individually function by function it works, but if I execute all, the 'result2' changes to '-1'. I don't understand why. I'm still checkinf if I can find why this happens! :(

Comment: If it works for each file individually, then try to store the output of file i in result2{i} (cell array or matrix, depending on its contents)

Comment: Thanks Dennis, thank you so much! I've tried with that line "text= {baseFileName, result2b, result3b, result4b, result5b};". I think it's what you mean, but I'm not pretty sure.